# EEPROM usage in LAN9500 USB to Ethernet IC

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, spi, eeprom

I'm using a Microchip [LAN 9500 USB 2.0 to Ethernet IC](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN9500) - [Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/LAN950x-Data-Sheet-DS00001875D.pdf)

However, I don't want to use the EEPROM section, and I don't want the IC to be connected to any EEPROM.

What do I have to do with the EEPROM pins and the EEPROM-associated configuration pins (pins 53 and 56) to run it in such a configuration?

My understanding is, since I am not using an EEPROM, so, I will leave the EEPROM pins (pins 29,30, 31 & 32)floating. I am not connecting anything to those pins as they have internal pull-up/pull-downs. Also, for the pins 53 and 56, they too have internal pullups and pulldowns. So, I will also leave them unconnected. This is my understanding. Is it correct?

Comment: Did you read the relevant chapters of the document you linked? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Yes I have gone through. I couldn't find on how to configure the pins if the EEPROM is not used? Like, I don't want to use an EEPROM. So, what should I do with those EEPROM pins and what about the pins 53 & 56 ?

Comment: You found tables 3-1 and 3-2, didn't you? Please [edit] your question and add what you concluded from the information, and what you are still missing. Please do _not_ add such information here, comments are not the right place.

Comment: My question is, since I am not using the EEPROM pins, should I leave the floating or pull-up/pull-down? And what am I supposed to do with the configuration strapping options of pin 53 & 56?

Comment: Again, a lot of information is in the data sheet. Supposed you have read it, what did you conclude from that, and why does it not help you? -- You don't want us to read all the details and dissect them to you, do you? We have no idea about your skills, and where exactly you are stumbling. I gave my crystal ball to someone who needed it urgently. You need to help us to help you.

Comment: My understanding is, since I am not using an EEPROM, so, I will leave the EEPROM pins (pins 29,30, 31 & 32)floating. I am not connecting anything to those pins as they have internal pull-up/pull-downs. Also, for the pins 53 and 56, they too have internal pullups and pulldowns. So, I will also leave them unconnected. This is my understanding. Is it correct @thebusybee ?

Comment: As I said, **please** add these statements to your question by [edit]ing it. -- If you leave the pins unconnected, do the pull-ups and pull-downs provide the level that your application needs? What levels do you expect for these pins?

Comment: Thank you. I've added them in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave the pins concerning the EEPROM unconnected, according to tables 3-1 and 3-2 of the linked data sheet, the inputs are pulled up and down, respectively.

| Pin | Name | Relevant type | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53 | EEP_SIZE | Pull up | Is irrelevant because of lack of EEPROM. (Size: 256/512 byte EEPROM) |
| 56 | EEP_DISABLE | Pull down | EEPROM is recognized if present. |
| 32 | EEDI | Pull down | Data input from EEPROM |
| 31 | EEDO | Output | Data output to EEPROM |
| 30 | EECS | Output | Chip select to EEPROM |
| 29 | EECLK | Output | Clock to EEPROM |

Please be aware that `EEP_SIZE` and `EEP_DISABLE` are only latched on reset. During operation, these pins have other functions.

Via the pull-down on `EEDI`, all data bits received will be zero. According to table 5-57, the first byte of a proper EEPROM shall be 0xA5, but is read as 0x00. Therefore, the chip will not recognize an EEPROM.

---

However, you should consider to pull up `EEP_DISABLE`, as this means "1 = EEPROM is **not** recognized even if it is present." (Emphasized by me. Just in case, for example in a noisy environment).

Chapter 8.5 has a lot of DC specifications.

The maximum input leakage current is 10µA. As the data sheets clearly states in note 8-1, the internal resistors add a current of typically 50µA.

If you choose to use such a pull-up resistor, it needs to pull up the level safely above the maximum of V<sub>IHT</sub>, which is 1.8V.

The minimum supply voltage is 3.3V - 300mV = 3.0V. Therefore, the maximum voltage drop at the resistor shall be less than 3.0 V - 1.8V = 1.2V.

By the law of Ohm the resistor should be no more than:

R = U / I = 1.2V / 0.060mA = 20kΩ

I would use a value a lot lower, let's say 10kΩ, just to be on the safe side.